# iOS filesystem HFS?

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone knows which filesystem the iOS use? I google it and didn't find anything
Thanks

Comment: Related: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83671/what-filesystem-does-ios-use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this [link here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus) they said that "**It is also one of the formats used by the iPod digital music player.**" so may be HFS and HFS+.

Answer (score 10):

It's **HFSX**.

According to "Mac OS X, IPod, and IPhone Forensic Analysis DVD Toolkit" book, the IPhone Partitioning scheme (which is quite similar to similar to Apple TV) contains:

1 - A ﬁrst Master Boot Record partition (around 500mb),

2 - followed by an Apple_Free area,

3 - then **a ﬁrst HFSX partition**, which primarily stores the iPhone's operating system.

4 - Again, another Apple_Free area

5 - and finally **the second HFSX partition** holding all user data (apps, movies, pictures, whatever)